# Jquery- .each() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have these buttons in my form that i want to bind 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' events to them this is the code that i wrote

```
$("button").each(function() {
  $(this).bind("mouseenter", function() { $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset") });
  $(this).bind("mouseleave", function() { $(this).css("border", "none") });
 });
```

this code only works on the first button and nothing happens to the rest.
this is my full code:

```
 $("button").each(function() {
 $(this).hover(function() { $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset") }, function() {   $(this).css("border", "none") });
    $(this).bind("mousedown",$(this).css( "border", "inset"));
    $(this).click(DoSubmit($(this), 'CLICK', ''));
    });
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted (http://jsfiddle.net/xJ6Ff/). Try setting up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net which shows the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsbin.com/uxiziq) (on Firefox).

Comment: Is this script included after the first button but before the other buttons by any chance? Or are you loading the other buttons with Ajax after you executed this function? There is nothing wrong with this code by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write directly :

```
$("button").mouseenter(function(){ $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset");}).mouseleave(function(){ $(this).css("border", "none");});
```

JS Fiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tkSdW/

Comment: This is equivalent to the code he's using... it won't *fix* anything.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Apologies if I'm missing something, but [there is no problem](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ6Ff)

Comment: @Rory: The code *is* equivalent. The OP's original code works (as Matt showed).  So if it does not work for the OP, this shouldn't either. That does not mean it should not be written this way (it should) but it won't be a solution for the OP's problem (*if there is a problem at all*). IMO we have to wait until (s)he clarifies...

Comment: You're right, apologies Matt. However, assigning handlers in an `each()` as the OP is still bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with your code

*providing that it is run after the DOM has loaded, that means inside*

```
$(function(){
   $('button')...
});
```

---

Additionally, you do not have to use each, if you are only using the iterations to bind events to the current element..

You can bind directly to a whole group with

```
$("button")
    .bind("mouseenter", function() { $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset") })
    .bind("mouseleave", function() { $(this).css("border", "none") });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to assign event handler in an `each()` loop. The selector alone will return an array of elements, and jQuery will then apply the event to those elements:

```
$(function() {
    $("button").bind("mouseenter", function() { $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset") });
    $("button").bind("mouseleave", function() { $(this).css("border", "none") });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bg2Z6/)

Answer (score 1):

While your original code [is working just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/LZCxf/) as it is, I would recommend using the `.hover()` method which is doing exactly the same thing but with less code:

```
$("button").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("border", "1px gray outset");
}, function() {
    $(this).css("border", "none");
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/LZCxf/1/).
 ​

Answer (score 1):

Your probably wanting this

```
$("button").each(function(index,value) {
   $(value).bind("mouseenter", function() { $(value).css("border", "1px gray outset"); });
   $(value).bind("mouseleave", function() { $(value).css("border", "none"); });
});
```